# Cakephp input form view as unordered list

Tags: forms, cakephp, input, html-lists

I'm developing a website using cakephp 2.x.

Now, I create a form using Cakedc/search. This form has input(select/dropdown list).
But the list is too long, so I want the dropdown to be view as unordered list (< ul >< li >).

Like in the lazada (search for brand): http://www.lazada.com.my/womens-watches-bags-accessories/.

the code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product', array(
    'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'search'), $this->params['pass'])));
      echo $this->Form->input('brand_id', array('label' => 'Brand', 'options' => $brands, 'empty' => 'Select Brand'));
<?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
     echo $this->Form->end();
 ?>
```

Please someone help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried already and what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript to get the id of the clicked li element or the link inside, use data attributes for that for example. Then set this value to a hidden form field or directly submit the whole form using ajax to update your results.

Your example URL is a simple list by the way that is just doing redirect on click.